# Chrome extension - after setTimeout script won't call anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying create a small Chrome extension that copies variables and pastes them on button click.

The issue I run into is that I display a small "alert" in popup.html, each time either button is clicked.

```
<div class="alert alert-success status hide" role="alert"></div>
```

The jQuery that I use is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".copy").click(function() {
        $(".status").removeClass('hide').text("You successfully copied the answers.");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".status").fadeOut();
        }, 5000);
    });

    $(".paste").click(function() {
        $(".status").removeClass('hide').text("You successfully pasted the answers.");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".status").fadeOut();
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

Now, how can I make sure that after `<div>` fades out I can still click either button and it will appear again?

Comment: you're showing it by removing a class, then hiding by setting css on the element itself ... perhaps you should `)....show().removeClass()...`

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! If you make an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. This question appears to be only about JavaScript/HTML/CSS,; consider using a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Specifically, we need the HTML which goes with your code. This does not appear to be Chrome extension specific, so we may not need a *manifest.json*. It does appear to be something that you could create a snippet which demonstrates the problem.  This question would be much better if you did so.